# Is $\mathbb{R}$ the smallest uncountable Zariski closed set in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and countably infinite zeroes of a complex function?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

I have few questions which are related to a problem I am solving. Let $v = (v_1,\dots, v_n)$ be a fixed vector in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $n>1$.

[1] Is $\mathbb{R}$ an algebraic set in $\mathbb{C}^n$ for $n>1$? Prove/disprove (by giving a counterexample).

[2] Is $\mathbb{C}$ the smallest uncountable (or probably even countably infinite) algebraic subset in $\mathbb{C}^n$?

[3] Claim: Let $f: \mathbb{C}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$  s.t. $f=0$ for all the points $\{mv: m \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \}$. Is it true that $f=0$ for all $\{mv: m \in \mathbb{C} \}$. Is there any theorem in complex analysis that has such a result.

Comment: The Zariski closure of $\Bbb{R}$ is $\Bbb{C}$

Comment: $X$ Zariski closed means $X$ is equal to its Zariski closure. The Zariski closure of $\Bbb{R}(1,0\ldots)$ contains $\Bbb{C}(1,0\ldots)$ because if $f(x_1,0,\ldots)$ vanishes on $\Bbb{R}$ then it vanishes on $\Bbb{C}$. The same holds for $\Bbb{R} v$ whose closure contains $\Bbb{C} v$. For $\Bbb{Z} v$ it depends if you mean the Zariski topology coming from algebraic sets or the one coming from analytic sets ($\sin \pi z$ vanishes only on $\Bbb{Z}$)

Comment: @reuns Your last line is very interesting. Can you explain this in detail? How does it vary? kindly give me some reference where I can find topology coming from algebraic sets and analytic sets. When I posted the problem, I had zariski topology coming from algebraic sets in my mind.

Comment: If a polynomial $\in \Bbb{C}[z]$ has infinitely many roots then it is identically $0$. If an entire function vanishes on $\Bbb{Z}$ it can be $\sin \pi z$ and have no other zeros. Thus $\Bbb{Z}$ is closed  as an analytic set but not as an algebraic set.

Comment: With $v =(1,0\ldots)$ then $ \Bbb{C}v$ is closed because it is the vanishing set of the ideal $(x_2,\ldots,x_n)$. For other $v$ you can use a complex linear change of variable to send it to $(1,0\ldots)$

Comment: @reuns I have one more doubt, because of the points of the form $mv$, I can easily see that there is a linear complex transformation that gives $(m,0,\dots)$ and then use the result. If I change the set of points to $v^r = (v_1^r,\dots,v_n^r): r \in \mathbb{N}$, do we have a non-linear transformation which still uses the same result as that of $\mathbb{C}(1,0,\dots) $.